# Do I get anything for playing the silver coin courses?

Tags: diddy-kong-racing-ds

I can pay Taj 20 banana coins to unlock the silver coin races (where you have to collect a certain number of silver coins on each track). I liked playing them on the N64 version, and find them to be more interesting than the balloon gathering touch challenge.

Is it worth paying to unlock these? Do I get balloons for winning them, or is it just for something extra to do?

Answer (score -1):

You will get a challenge which is:

> You get to race the boss again

source: http://www.funtrivia.com/en/VideoGames/Diddy-Kong-Racing-13340.html

Comment: This applies to the N64 version, I believe, which is different from the DS version.